# How to remove "X" in front of raster brick Names

Tags: r, raster, names

I need some help with the names format on my raster brick. I have a brick with 16 layers of wave height each with a time stamp of seconds since 1970. I can pull out the names and convert to standard date format. However when I try to re-insert the names to the rasterbrick an “X” get placed in front of each date stamp. This is preventing me from creating a date sliderInput in the shiny app as the max, min, and value arguments must be numeric.

I have found an old posting stating it is not possible. ([Why does R add an "x" when renaming raster stack layers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36844460/why-does-r-add-an-x-when-renaming-raster-stack-layers))

I am curious if any one knows of a work around?

Here is my code to downloading and cleaning the raster.

```
library(terra)
url <- "http://thredds.cdip.ucsd.edu//thredds/fileServer/cdip/model/MOP_grids/CA_0.01_forecast.nc"

options(timeout = 10000)
data_set <- "wave_data.nc"
if (!file.exists(data_set)) {
  download.file(url, data_set, mode="wb")
}
waves <- rast(data_set, sub = "waveHs")
ROU <- ext(-121.0062, -118.7438, 33.10625, 34.90625)
wave_crop <- crop(waves, ROU)

remove_txt <- gsub("waveHs_waveTime.", "", names(waves)) |> 
  as.numeric() |> 
  lubridate::as_datetime()

library(raster)
wave <- brick(wave_crop)
names(wave) <- remove_txt

wave
#class      : RasterBrick 
#dimensions : 180, 226, 40680, 16  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
#resolution : 0.009999997, 0.009999998  (x, y)
#extent     : -121.005, -118.745, 33.105, 34.905  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#crs        : +proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +no_defs 
#source     : memory
#names      : X2021.11.07.19.00.00, X2021.11.08.01.00.00, X2021.11.08.07.00.00, X2021.11.08.13.00.00, X2021.11.08.19.00.00, X2021.11.09.01.00.00, X2021.11.09.07.00.00, X2021.11.09.13.00.00, X2021.11.09.19.00.00, X2021.11.10.01.00.00, X2021.11.10.07.00.00, X2021.11.10.13.00.00, X2021.11.10.19.00.00, X2021.11.11.01.00.00, X2021.11.11.07.00.00, ... 
#min values :           0.08262682,           0.08607960,           0.08421428,           0.07400891,           0.06429628,           0.05832646,           0.05505765,           0.04826499,           0.03828974,           0.03100377,           0.02817857,           0.03242879,           0.03779505,           0.03922490,           0.05875918, ... 
#max values :             2.788141,             3.086087,             3.117096,             3.096558,             2.907296,             2.608371,             2.439595,             2.297133,             2.184082,             2.494745,             2.174670,             2.003929,             2.195310,             2.608896,             2.702595, ...
```

Comment: Names in R can’t begin with _ or a digit.

Comment: It's not quite correct that names cannot start with a digit, but such object names must be backticked to be access properly from the symbol table. I've got my doubts that showing you how to do this will solve your shiny problem, since such names are not really of numeric class and won't be recognized by the dispatch system as something that can be handled by functions or operators that expect numeric values. I think you should use `sub` to remove the leading "X" prior to `as.numeric` when you need to create a Date classed input to a slider function.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach would be to set the names to the SpatRaster `waves`, as `terra` does not enforce R name validity.

```
names(waves) <- remove_txt
waves
#class       : SpatRaster 
#dimensions  : 1000, 800, 16  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#resolution  : 0.009999997, 0.009999998  (x, y)
#extent      : -124.995, -116.995, 31.995, 41.995  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +no_defs 
#source      : wave_data.nc:waveHs 
#varname     : waveHs (significant wave height) 
#names       : 2021-~00:00, 2021-~00:00, 2021-~00:00, 2021-~00:00, 2021-~00:00, 2021-~00:00, ... 
#unit        :       meter,       meter,       meter,       meter,       meter,       meter, ... 

names(waves)
# [1] "2021-11-07 19:00:00" "2021-11-08 01:00:00" "2021-11-08 07:00:00"
# [4] "2021-11-08 13:00:00" "2021-11-08 19:00:00" "2021-11-09 01:00:00"
# [7] "2021-11-09 07:00:00" "2021-11-09 13:00:00" "2021-11-09 19:00:00"
#[10] "2021-11-10 01:00:00" "2021-11-10 07:00:00" "2021-11-10 13:00:00"
#[13] "2021-11-10 19:00:00" "2021-11-11 01:00:00" "2021-11-11 07:00:00"
#[16] "2021-11-11 13:00:00"
```

Alternatively, can't you use `remove_txt` for the labels in your `sliderInput`?

Comment: yes I can use that however, the slider and the map will not sync up since the names values are different. The slider will have the appropiate date but it will not change the map layers. I will attempt with terra but I think I ran into the problem of leaflet not allowing spat rasters.

Comment: You are right about leaflet not yet supporting SpatRasters, and I probably assumed wrong about what you can do with the slider

Comment: Yes your set up got the slider to work and had the correct dates